# notification on new user registration

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, notifications

I used two tutorials to create code which notifies me on a new user registration. [mail-notifications](http://laraveldaily.com/mail-notifications-customize-templates/) and [redirect-login-register-add-method/](http://laraveldaily.com/redirect-login-register-add-method/)

#### This works now

I am just sending a notification to default email defined here in my `User` model:

#### This is my desired goal

I want to send newly registered user's email in the emailed notification. Also, I wish to customize recipient for this specific `HelloUser` notification.

```
public function routeNotificationForMail()
{
    return 'name@gmail.com';
}
```

The notification is fired by the code in my `RegisterController.php`:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->notify(new \App\Notifications\HelloUser());
    return '/'; // redirects to main page
}
```

The above solution works, but I after many attempts I am still unable to get these extended result:

### to do 1

I will have several notifications, which I want to mail to 2-3 emails, not just one.

#### My attempt

In my notification file `App\Notifications\\HelloUser.php` I tried to add
extra line. (Note tha the line is now commented)

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('The new user email is ');
                // ->to('name@gmail.com');
}
```

... but I failed. I could define global recipient as described [here in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#customizing-the-recipient)

#### My question #1

How I can I define a separate recipient for each `Notification`?

### TO DO 2

I also tried to get the newly registered user's email into the emailed notification. 
For this purpose I tried to copy my solution from `Mailables`. So in `RegisterControler.php` I tried to pass $user variable in the function:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->notify(new \App\Notifications\HelloUser($user));
    return '/';
}
```

and then in my `Notification` file `App\Notifications\HelloUser` I did this:

```
public $user;

public function __construct($user)
{
    $email = $user->email;
}
```

in a hope that this piece would produce a notification with new user's email:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('The new user email is '.$user->email);
}
```

The result: I just get `Undefined variable: user`.

### TO DO

How to make this code work?

Thank you for your time.

=============
Edit:
upon @Arun_jai request I place here the dd($notifiable). It seems that it is generated properly and the object is just instance of the `User` model. The relevant part:

```
 #attributes: array:6 [▼
"name" => "Peter attempt 16"
"email" => "name@gmail.com"
"password" => "$2t9WHLFY14XNf0$nj7TYDYAxiZ/kdfrUy$1vC2"
"updated_at" => "2018-01-18 07:08:12"
"created_at" => "2018-01-18 07:08:12"
"id" => 270
]
```

Comment: can you do dd on $notifiable and see what you got please

Comment: I just updated my post with the `dd($notifiable)`. 
Please keep in mind that now I am only trying to customize the recipient for the `HelloUser` Notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the `Undefined variable: user` error, try instantiating the `$user` variable in your constructor, instead of the email. Your constructor should look like this:

```
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

Then you will be able to get the users' email by calling it with $this->user in any place of that class, so your MailMessage creation would look like this:

```
return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
            ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
            ->line('The new user email is ' . $this->user->email);
```

Comment: It does work! 
Seems I have missed out this variant `$this->user->email` in my `new MailMessage` response. 
Thank you